# matrix couple input from a user

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, input

"so i just started to learn python, now am against a real problem abt matrix i want to create a matrix by using an input from the user something like that : [[x,y],[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]],the first obvious solution is that to insert an array with 1D to a matrix on axis=0 but something went wrong with the dimensions on the console and also idk which function i use (like i said am new so looping through functions without knowing one of them really frustrated me)
so if anyone know  how to do, and a speciallly the rules to append and insert to an array or a matrix without geeting some dimensional error would be very helpfull and thnx for ur time "

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have tried? It's a bit difficult to parse your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a while loop that asks for user input until enough inputs have been passed through.

```
x = input('Enter x and y values (Ex. x,y): ')
lis, val = [], []

while 'n' not in x:
    val = x.split(',')
    lis.append(val)
    x = input('Enter x and y values (Ex. x,y): ') # stop loop by typing n

print(lis)
```

To end the loop just type 'n'.

Comment: This will append the list with `n` to `lis`. You should check for `n` *before* appending.

Comment: I generally recommend a style like `while True: x = input(...); if x == 'n': break; lis.append(x.split(','))`. This way you don't need to duplicate the input and split code before the loop, and don't need to pop.

Comment: so the comment line means that if the user enter 'n' the loop will stop and the list will be completed am less frustrated now,but for exmple if we ask for a number of rows first and then we enter couples(x,y) until the last row: is it abt the len(list) or somthing like that so that i must forget abt the axis idea and focus on performing a list methods ?

Comment: If you wanted that implementation you would just change to a for loop and write something like `for i in range(number_of_rows)` and then the same thing in the while loop would be in the for loop. Only change is that `x = input(...)` statement would come before the `val = x.split(',')`